# ADT plugin for eclipse helios on Win7 64 bit install error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install the ADT plugin for Eclipse and I get this error:

> An error occurred while installing the
>   items session context
>   was:(profile=epp.package.java,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install,
>   operand=null -->
>   [R]org.eclipse.jdt.debug
>   3.6.1.v20100715_r361, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
>   The artifact file for
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.6.1.v20100715_r361
>   was not found.

my OS: Win7 64bit

Eclipse version: Helios Service Release 2

Build id: 20110218-0911

ADT Plugin URL used: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

This is really starting to be confusing x.x

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)?

You can also try to download the adt zip file and try to install it as an archive
http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-11.0.0.zip

I have too win7 64bit and used Galileo, Helios and Indigo without any problem.

Comment: Aha! i got it, i just had to run eclipse with admin rights :)

Comment: Did you put it in the program files folder? You can put it on C:/ "custom folder" like I did and have no permission problems.